# componentWillUpdate() and componentDidUpdate() called with correct contents, render doesn't update

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this react component: https://gist.github.com/emilevictor/007a10aa1669829feb940b9548e582a1

I shoot off a redux saga to go fetch some data from the server. It is successfully set in this.props.statistics, and a re-render is triggered. The functions are correctly called in the following order when the state is changed in redux:

componentWillUpdate(...)
render(...)
componentDidUpdate(...)

That having been said, the DOM doesn't change to reflect the new numbers in this.props.statistics. Does anyone know what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to these two lines:

```
const LayoutWrapper = props => (
  <ChartWrapper>
    <Async
      load={import(/* webpackChunkName: "ReactChart2-layoutWrapper" */ "../../../components/utility/layoutWrapper")}
      componentProps={props}
    />
  </ChartWrapper>
);

const PageHeader = props => (
  <Async
    load={import(/* webpackChunkName: "ReactChart2-pageHeader" */ "../../../components/utility/pageHeader")}
    componentProps={props}
  />
);
```

Once removed, they fixed the issue. Would love some more detail on exactly why it had this effect though.